# While loop issue - Python

Tags: python, while-loop, structure, break

I've created a simple text-based game in Python which I'm using in conjunction with libPd (wrapper for Pure Data). All the game code was written before the audio was implemented and works as intended; similarly the libPd script itself also works perfectly on its own. However getting them to play nice together is proving to be tricky.

I assume it's to do with while loops and my usage of them.

Below is an extract from the game code -

```
    while True:

command = raw_input().lower()

    if command == "commands":
        print '"look around"'
        print '"explore"'
        print '"inventory"'
        print '"examine"'
        print '"take"'
        print '"combine"'
        print '"quit"'
    elif command == "look" or command == "look around":
        char.look()
```

...etc...
...etc...

While the libPd script on its own is as follows -

```
    while True:

if not ch.get_queue():
    for x in range(BUFFERSIZE):
            if x % BLOCKSIZE == 0:
                outbuf = m.process(inbuf)
            samples[selector][x][0] = outbuf[(x % BLOCKSIZE) * 2]
            samples[selector][x][1] = outbuf[(x % BLOCKSIZE) * 2 + 1]
    ch.queue(sounds[selector])
    selector = int(not selector)
libpd_release()
```

I originally tried indenting the entire game code within the libPd section but that caused the audio to only play once a command was typed, stopping once the print messages had been returned.

How do I go about combining the two so that the music is constant whilst the player is free to run through the rest of the commands/game?

Comment: sounds like you might be looking for multiple threads. One to have the game loop and antoher to play the music.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the concepts of threading. Your audio will need to run in a different thread from your game code. Check out Python's [threading module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have to sit around waiting for `raw_input()` to return, but at the same time you have to keep processing audio messages off the queue as soon as they come in. How can you do both at the same time?

---

First, there's the event-loop style that you're using today.

If you can write a function that waits on either input or audio messages, whichever comes first you can rewrite your program around a loop that waits on that function. This is hard to do in general. (GUI frameworks and network server frameworks can help, but either would be a bit silly for your text game.)

You can fake it by only waiting a short time for each line, e.g., by using `select.select` on `sys.stdin` with a short timeout. But this is a lot of work, and it's hard to balance responsiveness and performance with a design like that.

---

Alternatively, you can use threads. Here's what it would look like:

```
def play_music():
    while True:
        if not ch.get_queue():
            for x in range(BUFFERSIZE):
                    if x % BLOCKSIZE == 0:
                        outbuf = m.process(inbuf)
                    samples[selector][x][0] = outbuf[(x % BLOCKSIZE) * 2]
                    samples[selector][x][1] = outbuf[(x % BLOCKSIZE) * 2 + 1]
            ch.queue(sounds[selector])
            selector = int(not selector)
        libpd_release()

play_music_thread = threading.Thread(target=play_music)
play_music_thread.daemon = True
play_music_thread.start()

while True:
    command = raw_input().lower()

    if command == "commands":
        print '"look around"'
        print '"explore"'
        print '"inventory"'
        print '"examine"'
        print '"take"'
        print '"combine"'
        print '"quit"'
    elif command == "look" or command == "look around":
        char.look()
```

If you want to be able to do clean shutdown, instead of just having the music thread killed in the middle of whatever it's doing when you quit, it's a bit more complicated… but not that much. Basically, with a `Condition`, `Event`, `Queue`, or just a boolean variable and a `Lock`, you can easily build a way to signal the background music thread from the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I tried the threading solution as you posted it but it was a no-go in terms of audio output. Am I missing something simple? There's an audible click as if it initializes briefly but nothing after that. I had a similar result whilst trying to combine the two initially before I posted this Question.

Comment: @CapricornOne: Without seeing the rest of your code, it's hard to be sure… but I suspect that you're trying to share some variable between the music thread and some other code in the main thread—maybe `selector` is a shared global, or maybe `ch.get_queue()` is using a `list` instead of a `Queue.Queue`, or maybe you're trying to clear the queued-up buffer while the other thread is trying to play it, or…?

Comment: In general, for any object that's used by two threads, you have to share a `Lock` as well, and then write `with mylock:` around each line or chunk or code that modifies or access the object. Self-synchronizing types like `Queue` and `Lock`, and immutable types like `int` and `tuple`, don't need this, but anything else generally does.

Comment: I thought that "selector" was the issue originally but I'm just not sure. There also shouldn't be any crossover with the two threads as far as I can tell. If you'd like to take a look at the full code I've upped it here http://pastebin.com/mW8yKFYG

Comment: Try moving the `inbuf`, `ch`, `sounds`, and `samples` variables all into the top of the `play_music` function, and also the stuff at the top of the file (`BUFFERSIZE = 4096` through `patch = libpd_open_patch`). That ensures that you're not touching libpd or pygame at all from the main thread.

Comment: Hmm.. No luck. I even tried isolating the libpd section of code (with the changes you suggested) like so - http://pastebin.com/kpFcSc8W but the audio just initializes for a split second before dropping out again. I'm not sure if you can run one thread on its own but it sounds like an issue with the while loop. Here's a link to the original libpd code that works flawlessly http://pastebin.com/zmJ0qgVj

Comment: Wait, hold on… In your example, you start the `play_music` daemon thread, and then immediately quit. Quitting the main thread kills all daemon threads. For this test, get rid of the `daemon = True` part, and instead put `play_music_thread.join()` after the `start()` line. That shouldn't affect your _real_ program, because it isn't quitting until you leave the big `while` loop… but get the test program working first, then come back to the bigger one.

Comment: Like so - http://pastebin.com/midunmu0 ? No joy, same result. Really appreciate the help, I'd move this discussion to chat as recommended but I don't have enough rep..

Comment: Do you get the "automatically move this discussion to chat" link, and then an error when you click on it? Never mind… It's possible that something about `pygame.mixer` and/or `pylibpd` has to stay on the main thread. (That's true for a lot of GUI libraries; usually not for sound libraries, but… you never know.) So, try moving the _main_ program onto a background thread, and having the main thread kick off the background thread, then just run `play_music` directly. (It'll be harder to get quit to work this way, but don't worry about that for now.)

Comment: Ok, after some playing with it I think it's actually due to your initial suggestion in that "selector" isn't being utilized properly. In the original libpd code (which works) here - http://pastebin.com/1nTgYny6 , it is set as a global variable. Whereas in the threading test - http://pastebin.com/kysYs9DB , the console returns the error "local variable 'selector' referenced before assignment". If I place it within the play_music function it starts cutting out again.

Comment: Well, it's illegal to access a global variable, and then assign it later in the same function, without a `global` declaration. But if `selector` isn't being used anywhere but `play_music`, and that's only being called once, that isn't really relevant here; you could add `global selector` to the top of the function and get the same behavior as you would moving it local. Anyway, did you try switching the threads so `play_music` is on the main thread and everything else is in the background?

Comment: Like so? http://pastebin.com/mb61510t . This gives me the "local variable 'selector' referenced before assignment" error and when I move selector into the function it just reverts back to the same story - initializing for a split second before cutting out. Quite frustrating.

Comment: No, that has the same problem with `selector` as before; if you're only using it inside `play_music`, just initialize it there as a local variable. More importantly, it doesn't switch the threads so `play_music` is on the main thread and everything else is in the background. For a trivial example: http://pastebin.com/bPSndtSw

Comment: Finally got it to work in a test environment using two separate threads. I used the following syntax http://pastebin.com/zfS67Znw . Attempting to implement the rest of the code now.

Comment: Works perfectly. Really appreciated the help. Thanks for everything. The last thing I wanted to do was switch out the PD patch ('basement'.pd in this case) depending on which room the player enters but I suppose that'll be another days work. Thanks again.

Comment: @CapricornOne: Yeah, if you get stuck on that, create a new question. But to get you started: You'll probably want to actually signal the music thread from the game thread for that, rather than just swap out the patch in mid-buffer (because that would sound awful). You can do that with a `Condition`, `Event`, or `Queue` that you check each time through the music thread loop, and just notify/post from the game thread.

Answer (score 1):

The `while True:` loops in your code are "blocking", which means that while that loop is running then no other loop runs on the same thread.  A simple example of running multiple threads is:

```
import threading
import time

class MyGame(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # an "event" is used to tell the threads when to stop
        # this is "thread safe", meaning it can be used by a number
        # of different threads without causing problems
        self.stop_event = threading.Event() 

        # create and start a thread to run your sound
        self.sound_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.sound, args=[self.stop_event])
        print "Starting sound thread"
        self.sound_thread.start()

        # create and start a thread to run your game
        self.game_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.game, args=[self.stop_event])
        print "Starting game thread"
        self.game_thread.start()

    def sound(self, stop_event):
        print "Entering sound thread"
        while not stop_event.is_set():
            # put the bit that used to be in the While True loop in here
            time.sleep(0.5)
        print "Exiting sound thread"

    def game(self, stop_event):
        print "Entering game thread"
        while not stop_event.is_set():
            # put the bit that used to be in the While True loop in here
            time.sleep(0.5)
        print "Exiting game thread"

    def stop(self):
        """Used to stop the threads from running"""
        print "Stopping threads"
        self.stop_event.set()

        self.sound_thread.join()
        print "Sound thread stopped"

        self.game_thread.join()
        print "Game thread stopped"
```

Have a look at the [Python Threading documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) for more information - its very thorough.  To run the program you would do something like:

```
game = MyGame()
time.sleep(2)
game.stop()
```

In your console you will see something like

```
>>> Starting sound thread
>>> Entering sound thread
>>> Starting game thread
>>> Entering game thread
>>> Stopping threads
>>> Exiting sound thread
>>> Sound thread stopped
>>> Exiting game thread
>>> Game thread stopped
```